# how to get the position from the custom adapter

Tags: android-layout, adapter

In myactivity I have created one custom adapter for the listview.I have an array with one element. when I called setadapter method then the getView method running for 10 time.

Any one help me on this...

Answer (score 0):

You have to have an inner class manytimes called ViewHolder from the api demos. There you can set an Integer called position.

Set holder.position=position if the convertView == null;
Then set the holder (ViewHolder object) as tag to the convertView. Eatch time you want to see what position is the ConvertVIew in, get the tag cast it to ViewHolder object and access the position from there.